# which thread to run the code-behind in graphical user interface such as Windows Forms, WPF?

Tags: c#, .net

I know only GUI thread can update UI component and in order to compute long running tasks we have to use thread pool to do the hard work and create a continuation task to update UI using the synchronization context task scheduler.

Here is a simple Windows Forms application

```cs
internal sealed class MyForm : Form 
{
    private readonly TaskScheduler m_syncContextTaskScheduler;
    
    public MyForm() 
    {
        m_syncContextTaskScheduler = 
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        Text = "Synchronization Context Task Scheduler Demo";
    }

    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e) 
    {
        // This task uses the default task scheduler and executes on a thread pool thread
        Task<Int32> t = Task.Run(...);
        // This task uses the sync context task scheduler and execute on the GUI thread
        t.ContinueWith(task => Text = "Result: " + task.Result, 
            CancellationToken.None, 
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, 
            m_syncContextTaskScheduler);
        ...
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
   }
}
```

My quesiton is quite simple, which thread to this run the code-behind such as `OnMouseClick` method? Is it the GUI thread itself that execute this code-behind, so only two threads involved, one GUI thread and one worker thread? or a worker thread run this code behind, so one GUI thread and two worker threads involved?

Answer (score 1):

The handlers for UI-generated events is executed in UI thread. So, in your code `OnMouseClick` will be also executed in UI thread. The `Task` will be executed on a thread defined by scheduler (typically, it will be thread pool's thread).

Technically, some code can call your `OnMouseClick` in the non-UI thread, but it is bad practice and standard WinForms/WPF controls will not do such a things.

Also please note that thread pool typically has more then one thread for tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple test on my simple WPF application, in both my MainWindow() ctor and in my btnMouseClick(), I print out the thread id `{System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}`
and both out puts 1, as you can imagine. So yes the GUI thread is executing the code in your `OnMouseClick`, then your new task is on a worker thread.